# RabbitMQ pika connection errors and inconsistency

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

```
def response(return_JSON):
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=HOST))
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.exchange_declare(exchange=EXCHANGE, type='direct', durable='True')
    channel.queue_declare(queue=QUEUE_NAME, durable='True')
    channel.queue_bind(exchange=EXCHANGE, queue=QUEUE_NAME)
    channel.basic_publish(exchange=EXCHANGE, routing_key=RESPONSE_ROUTING_KEY, body=return_JSON)
    connection.close()  
    print "  [x] Finished sending msg to sender..."


def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print "  [x] Received message from sender!"
    print body
    result_JSON = Work().compute(json.loads(body))
    if result_JSON is not None:
        #result_JSON = json.dumps(result_JSON)
        response(result_JSON)
        channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)
        print "Acknowledged to sender"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=HOST))
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue=QUEUE_NAME, durable='True')
    channel.basic_consume(callback, queue=QUEUE_NAME, no_ack=False)
    print "  [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C"
    channel.start_consuming()
```

This often works for a while and then falls over. Only need to consume messages one at a time, process them and send back a response message with a different routing KEY. Is there a smarter more reliable way to create a minimal consumer processing messages one at a time.

Error message is:

```
Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Why are you sending the response with a different routing key? In what context is this a response?

Comment: Which instruction exactly raise that exception?